# Criar colunas com o foreach do knockoutJS

Tags: javascript, foreach, knockoutjs

Boa tarde, eu queria 'partir' uma lista de items em 3 colunas de 4 items num foreach do knockoutJS.

Ou seja, neste momento a lista é preenchida para baixo e eu gostaria que ela fosse partida via jQuery ou javascript, porque o CSS não é suportado no IE9

Agradeço a ajuda !

```js
var lbx = {};
var json = {
  "items": [{
    "key": 13,
    "value": "A. E. Brehm"
  }, {
    "key": 14,
    "value": "Achille Murat"
  }, {
    "key": 15,
    "value": "Adolphe Siret"
  }, {
    "key": 16,
    "value": "Adrien Balbi"
  }, {
    "key": 18,
    "value": "Albereto de Oliveira"
  }, {
    "key": 19,
    "value": "Alberto dos Reis"
  }, {
    "key": 20,
    "value": "Albino Forjaz de Sampaio"
  }, {
    "key": 21,
    "value": "Alexandre Dumas"
  }, {
    "key": 22,
    "value": "Alexandre Herculano"
  }, {
    "key": 23,
    "value": "Alfredo França"
  }, {
    "key": 24,
    "value": "Allen Ginsberg"
  }, {
    "key": 25,
    "value": "Alphonse Allais"
  }],
  "totalItems": 261
};

lbx.vm = {
  term: ko.observableArray(),
};


lbx.vm.term.push(json);

console.log(lbx.vm.term());

$(function() {

  ko.applyBindings(lbx.vm);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="list-unstyled" data-bind="foreach: term">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="text: value">
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, encontrei esse exemplo de outra pessoa em outro fórum americano. Talvez te ajude.

Pelo que entendi ele usa um `ko.computed` para trabalhar com as colunas, não esquecendo de determinar a quantidade de colunas.

Acredito que isso possa te ajudar.

```js
var viewModel = {
  items: ko.observableArray(),
  columnLength: ko.observable(5)
};

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  viewModel.items.push({
    name: 'test' + i
  });
}

//return an array of rows.  Each row is an array of items
viewModel.rows = ko.computed(function() {
  var result = [],
    row,
    colLength = parseInt(this.columnLength(), 10);

  //loop through items and push each item to a row array that gets pushed to the final result
  for (var i = 0, j = this.items().length; i < j; i++) {
    if (i % colLength === 0) {
      if (row) {
        result.push(row);
      }
      row = [];
    }
    row.push(this.items()[i]);
  }

  //push the final row  
  if (row) {
    result.push(row);
  }

  return result;
}, viewModel);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="value: columnLength" />
<hr/>

<table data-bind="foreach: rows">
  <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Créditos ao:** ***rniemeyer*** da comunidade **JSFiddle**

Comment: @RodrigoGuiotti acho que é isso? Caso esteja errado, me ajude. Sou novo no fórum.

Comment: Era mesmo isto que queria, obrigado pela ajuda!